# How to run a script on a Google Compute Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

You can run a startup-script and a shutdown-script, but is it possible to use the Compute Engine API to run a script after startup?

The primary reason I'm asking is because the startup script isn't executing for me upon first run

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "startup script isn't executing for me upon first run"?  Defining a startup-script mean a script that is executed after boot ... and feels like the correct solution to the problem so we might want to examine what is going wrong there.

Comment: Definitively needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. You can pass the file through a gcloud command or just add it to the instance metadata using the UI. Take a look at the following documentation for [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptlocalfile) and [shutdown-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#provide_a_shutdown_script_file).

Comment: This is possible through --command

Answer (score 0):

Use the --command to copy the script from a gcs bucket to the running compute instance and then use the --command again to execute the script in the running instance.

gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a --command